# Error in path in GlassFish app when using Nginx

Tags: jakarta-ee, nginx, glassfish-3

my app is on my server and works fine at:
http://vps465.ns.planethoster.net:8080/Calenicon/

(so the context root of the GlassFish app is /Calenicon)

The domain name is http://www.calenicon.rog

The nginx config is simply:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  calenicon.org www.calenicon.org;


    location / {
        proxy_pass      http://localhost:8080/Calenicon/;
        proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    }
```

But then accessing http://www.calenicon.org shows an unnecessary "/Calenicon" being inserted in all relative paths? (try clicking on the link "why this app" - delete the "/Calenicon" part in the path to see it working again.)

Could anybody point me to a solution? Thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The link on your landing page is generated by the upstream app server. Without changing that, you have to tell nginx how to serve that url. One solution could be adding the following location block:

```
location /Calenicon/ {
    proxy_pass      http://localhost:8080;
    proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
}
```